# Javascript gettime()

Tags: javascript, gettime

I am trying to use gettime to sort my date string. But it is returning some vague values like.

1. 1428303000000 16/06/2014 16:50
2. 1389074040000 01/07/2014 16:54

The first date is smaller than second so its no. of milliseconds should also be smaller.

You can also check it on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-binpractice.cgi?file=javascript_178

So don't know why this is behaving like this.

Any help ?

Comment: Yes, the link is not working. Try using JSFiddle.

Comment: Are you are doing something like `new Date('16/06/2014 16:50')`? Because `new Date(1428303000000)` is sometime about 6 April, 2015.

Comment: The link where i was testing is http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-bin/practice.cgi?file=javascript_178

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test your code if you are correctly creating `Date` object

```
// new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond);

// Working with date 16/06/2014 16:50
var foo = new Date(2014, 6, 16, 16, 50);
foo.getTime(); // 1405518600000

// Working with date 01/07/2014 16:54 
var foo = new Date(2014, 7, 1, 16, 54);
foo.getTime(); // 1406901240000
```

Read more about [Date object reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Until we see your code and how do you get from "16/06/2014 16:50" to "1428303000000", I can't help more.

Comment: I tested this like <script type="text/javascript">
   var dt = new Date( "16/06/2014 16:50" );
   document.write("getTime() : " + dt.getTime() ); 
</script>

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work like that. I'm glad I helped you understand your mistake by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably creating the date using `16/06/2014` and intending this to mean the 16th day of the 6th month. However, this is not how it's parsed. The *first* element is treated as the month; the second element is the day. Since there aren't 16 months in a year, the date is rounded forward to the next year (i.e. the 16th month of 2014 is the 4th month of 2015).

In other words:

```
Date.parse("16/06/2014 16:50") === Date.parse("04/06/2015 16:50"); // => true
```

Comment: Bottom line: **don't use Date.parse**. The OP is ending up with an implementation dependent result (if browsers think that is the 16th month, they should probably return NaN since it's an invalid date).

Comment: Well, certainly don't give it dates in unsupported formats.

Comment: The problem is that there is one standardised format for use with *Date.parse* and it's not what the OP is using, nor is it supported consistently by all browsers in use. Some don't support the standardised format at all. :-(

Comment: You're definitely right about implementation-specific behavior, though. For example, Firefox's behavior is explained here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse